# ActionScript3: in one class read file by addEventListener, how to pass data to a different class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

There are many questions similar to mine, but none of them are solving particular to my problem.

I have this class -

```
package com.test
{
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.net.*;
    
    import com.test.LogUtils;
    import mx.logging.ILogger;
    
    public class LoadExtUrl extends EventDispatcher
    {
        private var baseUrl:String;
        private var log:ILogger = LogUtils.getLogger(LoadExtUrl);
        
        public function LoadExtUrl()
        {
            log.debug ("100 In LoadExtUrl()");
            super(null);
        }
        
        public function loadBaseUrl():String
        {
            var loader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
            loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, urlLoader_completeHandler);
            
            function urlLoader_completeHandler(event:Event):void
            {
                var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(event.target);
                this.baseUrl = loader.data.baseurl;
                dispatchEvent(new Event("GOTRESULTS"));
                log.debug ("200 In LoadExtUrl, baseUrl="+this.baseUrl);
            }
            
            loader.load(new URLRequest("sri-config-files/url.properties"));
            
            log.debug ("300 In LoadExtUrl, baseUrl="+this.baseUrl);
            return this.baseUrl;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to read the value of baseUrl in many other classes.

In another class I have the following code -

```
public class UrlHelper
{
    public static var myLoadExtUrl:LoadExtUrl = new LoadExtUrl();
    public static var baseUrl:String;
    
    public function UrlHelper()
    {}
    
    public static function getBaseUrl():void
    {
        myLoadExtUrl.addEventListener("GOTRESULTS", xmlLoadCompleted);
        log.debug("400 In UrlHelper, baseUrl ="+baseUrl);
    }
    
    private static function xmlLoadCompleted(e:Event):void 
    {
        baseUrl=myLoadExtUrl.loadBaseUrl();
        log.debug("500 In UrlHelper, baseUrl ="+baseUrl);
    }
}
```

Logging sequence -

```
100 In LoadExtUrl()
300 In LoadExtUrl, baseUrl=null
200 In LoadExtUrl, baseUrl=http://abcxyz.com:8080/

400 In UrlHelper, baseUrl =null --> here only I need the value
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Because **sendUrl(...)** method does not return anything. Thus, you are not getting anything with **baseUrl = myLoadExtUrl.sendUrl();**

Comment: Hi @Organis: thanks. I corrected the code. Actually I was trying with so many options and pasted the wrong code here. sendUrl() is not returning anything, it's void. But within sendUrl() also after calling the addEventListener(), the value is null. Becuase addEventListener() is not a blocking call. So I tried to get the value in sendUrl() and return it, by even then it's not working - 
`public function sendUrl():String
{
     .......
     loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, handleComplete);
     loader.load(request);
     trace(baseUrl); -> NULL
     return baseUrl;
}`

Comment: Loading is asynchronous by definition, therefore you will only receive a valid baseUrl upon receiving `Event.COMPLETE` dispatched by the loader. So, you do `myLoadExtUrl.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE,getThatUrl); function getThatUrl(e:Event=null) { this.baseUrl=myLoadExtUrl.baseUrl;}`

Comment: Hi @Vesper: yes, I already did it. Please check UrlHelper.xmlLoadCompleted() function. I marked it as strong. Here I have put baseUrl=myLoadExtUrl.baseUrl; I am getting the value within this function, but not within UrlHelper.getBaseUrl(). How to resolve it?

Comment: @NirmalyaSinha Ok, now you don't even try putting anything into **UrlHelper.baseUrl** so it is, obviously, null. Also, as Vesper pointed out, if you get that data from loaded data,  it is, again, obviously, unavailable at the moment you are starting the loading process.

Comment: Hi @Organis: I tried a lot to fix this issue in the weekend, but couldn't. This is a typical asynchronous problem with event handlers. There are many QA, like - [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073727/addeventlistener-with-ruturn-in-as3-how] or [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8378027/actionscript-3-how-to-keep-the-value-from-an-event-after-removing-that-event] or [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6712688/async-operation-in-actionscript], but I am not getting the solution! I have used another eventDispatcher "GOTRESULTS", but didn't help me. Please check the edited post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I need to write down some explanations.

What is **asynchronous** operation? It is an operation that

- takes some (initially unknown or undeterminable) time to complete
- does not block the code execution, to put it simply, when you start loading the code doesn't stop to wait the operation to complete, it immediately starts executing the rest of the code with no regard to that operation status

Thus, the actual flow of events in the thing you are building is:

1. UH class tells LEU class to start loading
2. ... some time passes ...
3. LEU class detects the end of loading process.
4. Loaded data are available.
5. LEU dispatches custom event.
6. UH detects the event and finally **CAN** obtain the data.

So, the LoadExtUrl class:

```
package
{
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.EventDispatcher;
    
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
    
    public class LoadExtUrl extends EventDispatcher
    {
        private var baseUrl:String;
        private var loader:URLLoader;
        
        // Interface method.
        public function loadBaseUrl():String
        {
            var aRequest:URLRequest;
            
            // Form the HTTP request.
            aRequest = new URLRequest;
            aRequest.url = "sri-config-files/url.properties";
            
            // Initiate the loading process.
            loader = new URLLoader;
            loader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.VARIABLES;
            loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoad);
            loader.load(aRequest);
            
            // Data are NOT available yet at this point.
        }
        
        // Data loading COMPLETE handler.
        private function onLoad(e:Event):void
        {
            // Data are AVAILABLE at this point.
            
            // Extract the data.
            baseUrl = loader.data.baseurl;
            
            // Clean up.
            loader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoad);
            loader = null;
            
            // Tell anyone willing to listen about the data availability.
            var anEvent:Event;
            
            // Feel free to use predefined constants instead of custom
            // event names. It will protect you against typo errors.
            anEvent = new Event(Event.COMPLETE);
            dispatchEvent(anEvent);
        }
    }
}
```

How to use it:

```
public class UrlHelper
{
    static public var baseUrl:String;
    
    static private var loadExt:LoadExtUrl;
    
    // Interface method.
    static public function getBaseUrl():void
    {
        // Data are NOT available yet at this point.

        loadExt = new LoadExtUrl;

        // Data are NOT available yet at this point.
        
        // Subscribe to the very same event name
        // that class is going to dispatch.
        loadExt.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onAnswer);

        // Data are NOT available yet at this point EITHER.
        // Loading is an asynchronous operation. We started
        // the loading but we have to wait until the data are available.
    }
    
    // This handler will be invoked when data are available.
    static private function onAnswer(e:Event):void 
    {
        // Data are AVAILABLE at this point.
        
        // Extract the data.
        baseUrl = loadExt.baseUrl;
        
        // Clean up.
        loadExt.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onAnswer);
        loadExt = null;
        
        // You are free to use the obtained data at this point.
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Organis, this clears my doubt. In my code also I was getting the same behaviour and wondering whether that is correct. Looks like that the remaining portion of the code is to be kept within the onAnswer() function. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: @NirmalyaSinha Exactly, the rest of the code should be placed into **onAnswer()** because it is the point where the data you need are available.